# How to load local file for Python SVM application

Tags: python, svm

I have a python code that does basic SVM calculations on the famous iris document. However, I have a local file named as mydata.csv-on my desktop--(users\servar\desktop\mydata.csv (looks like below) that I want to replace for iris (so I want to run my code on the local file), not quite sure how I should do as I already tried a few ways but failed

```
B1,B2,A1,A2,RESULTS
AB,RE,RE,FWE,A1
AB,SE,RE,FWE,B1
AB,RE,SD,FQW,A1
.........


from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.svm import SVC
dataset = datasets.load_iris()
model = SVC()
model.fit(dataset.data, dataset.target)
print(model)
expected = dataset.target
predicted = model.predict(dataset.data)
print(metrics.classification_report(expected, predicted))
print(metrics.confusion_matrix(expected, predicted))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would check out this (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/) and suggest you become more familiar with pandas (http://pandas.pydata.org/) and numpy.  But here is one way I would do what you are trying to do:

```
import csv
csvReader = csv.reader(open('yourcsv.txt'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
x = []
xpart = []
y = []
for row in csvReader:
    for i in range(len(row)):
        if i != (len(row) - 1):
            xpart.append(row[i])
        else:
            y.append(row[i])
    x.append(xpart)
    xpart = []
model = SVC()
model.fit(x, y)
```